# Serialize a list of strings where each element in the list is an element in the XML with Java SimpleXml

Tags: java, arraylist, xmlserializer, simple-framework

I am trying to serialize a couple of objects to xml with simplexml in Java. I have the following objects:

```
@Root()
class foo {
    @ElementList
    List<bar> foo;
}

@Root()
class bar {
    @Element
    String bar;
}
```

and the output is:

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <bar>a</bar>
    </bar>
    <bar>
        <bar>b</bar>
    </bar>
    ...
</foo>
```

but, what i want is:

```
<foo>
    <bar>a</bar>
    <bar>b</bar>
    ...
</foo>
```

Any idea how this can be achieved? I'm working with legacy code and unfortunately I can't change the xml structure at all. I have a feeling that I probably need to create a custom serializer for the foo object so that the outer bar isn't serialized. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't change XML, why don't you change Java class? For example List<bar> foo; -> List<String> foo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [`@Text` annotation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#text) to add text to the bar element:

```
@Root()
class bar {
    @Text
    String bar;
}
```